# How to make a button's associated menu plain?

Tags: extjs4

I'm trying to remove the incised line down the left side of the menu + indentation. How exactly do I set the menu's [plain config](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.menu.Menu-cfg-plain) in this context?

```
Ext.create('Ext.button.Button', {
    text: 'Manage',            
    arrowAlign: 'right',
    menu: [{
        text: 'Object',
        iconCls: 'object',
        menu: [
             Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel')
        ]
    }]
});
```

---

EDIT: Got it working by creating the menu outside of the button and then assigning the button's menu to it. The 'plain : true' and 'showSeparator : false' flags worked then.

Comment: Did you try In the menu config showSeparator : false

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to See if this works

```
 Ext.create('Ext.button.Button', {
    text: 'Manage',            
    arrowAlign: 'right',
    menu: [{
    text: 'Object',
    plain : true,
    showSeparator : false
    iconCls: 'object',
    menu: [
         Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel')
    ]
  }]
});
```

Comment: Nope, but I didn't think to set showSeparator to false earlier. Put me on the right track - thanks!